# how to select the word by click on screen

Tags: android

I want to select one word from a text by click screen. Not use spannable or listener. Maybe should change something from the source code just like framework.

Just like the picture in this page: http://bbs.csdn.net/topics/390694750.

Thank your!

Comment: You need to create GestureDetector for this and Copy your text into ClipboardManager and get from it.

Comment: thank for your advise.but what I want is that we could select the word from every text,not only the one we make.